# How to access the Firefox history remotely

Tags: firefox, remote, firefox-extensions, history

I want to monitor the Firefox history of a PC from another remotely. Is there any add on or something else which exports and uploads / syncs Firefox history to an FTP server so that I can access it from somewhere else?

I am not looking for a key logger or similar solution. I just want the browsing history only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firefox Sync and configure to sync History only but it can sync many other things like favorites or passwords for example. It is now included in Firefox and needs only configuration, no install: [Firefox Sync](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/sync/)

I don't know what you want to do but beware, this will syncronize what you choose to sync between the 2 (or more) browsers and they will be the same so you will have the same history (or whatever you choose to sync) on both machines. You will receive the history from the remote machine in your browser history and you will export yours to it too.